# The best way for checking the same structures?

Tags: c#

So i'm creating a video game for my little sister and im looking for the best way for checking the same structure. What i mean... We have 2 classes 'Test 1.cs' and 'Test2.cs' + enum class like 'DoSomething with 2 solutions like Make1, Make2.

And.. In the class Test1.cs we have code like

```
[Serializable]
public struct Abc{
public DoSometing DoSomething.Make1;
}
public Abc[] abcList;
```

Ofc we have the same method in the class Test2.cs
And what is the best way to check when struct abcList with Make1 is equal abcList from Test2 when they have the same DoSomething?

Example:

```
void Test(){
for (int i = 0; i<abcList.Lenght; i++){
//another loop from other class with the same struct
for (int ii = 0; ii<abcList2.Length; i++){
//so 
if (abcList[i].DoSomething == abcList2[ii].DoSomething){
//ITS TRUE
}
```

Have you got any good solutions for this?

Comment: you're *already* checking whether two items have the same `DoSomething`... I'm very unclear what the question is here - could you perhaps clarify or rephrase? also: I wonder whether `struct` is useful here - this looks like something that should be a `class`

Comment: I'm asking about better solution for this. I'm not pretty sure it's the best way

Comment: Are you basically just trying to check the enum 'DoSomething' in 1 loop iteration against another loop iteration?

Comment: Exactly, but i need a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if(class1.Abclist.Equals(class2.Abclist))
{
//Do something
}
```

Comment: I am looking for the best way instead of using loop

Comment: The best way can be this bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1, array2);

Comment: Could you give me an example code with using ur solution?

Comment: Try this: bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1, array2);

Comment: This is better! But how to set if isEqual is true array1 the same parameter as in array2

Comment: I mean that if parameter one has the same enum like parameter two, then parameter one sets the same variable which have parametr two

Comment: Hmmm.... if you have to do something when they are equal , using 2 for loops is the best way in my opinion, my method only tell you if the 2 arrays have the same values.